# how to sync chat data by using json api without overloading the server

Tags: c#, windows, binding, chat, uwp

I need to sync the chat data by sending HTTP get request to a server. the View model doesn't update its data unless the user presses the send(for sending a new message) or the user goes back and again lands to the chat page. I thought of implementing a task which sends HTTP request for every 5 secs,even then there will be a great lag in the chat,plus the server would be overloaded. Any suggestions?

Comment: by the way it is an universal windows app(win 10)

Comment: It's your server or 3rd party? If it's yours you could change the server to inform the corresponding clients...?

Comment: It is our own server. Any idea how to implement listener in WIN10

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically want non persistent connections/polling between your clients and servers (which would also mean disabling HTTP connection pooling), I'd go for a push based implementation meaning the client connects to the server and maintains that connection until it is done with the chat session.

You could try these libraries (both of which are aimed at a higher level than raw sockets) to get you going:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh969243.aspx

http://sta.github.io/websocket-sharp/ [web socket library]

http://zeromq.org/ [mainly aimed at non-http based connections]